# XSL Transformation for Complex Attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, complexity-theory, xslt-2.0

Im new to XSLT . I have an XML message as below :

```
<Root>
<Payload>
    <SendEmail>
        <customerID>123123</customerID>
        <subscriberID>123123</subscriberID>         
        <MessageDetails>
            <AttributeList>
                <Attribute Name="CcEmailAddress">abc@abc.com</Attribute>
                <Attribute Name="BcccEmailAddress">abc@abc.com</Attribute>
                <Attribute Name="SenderEmailAddress">abc@abc.com</Attribute>
                <Attribute Name="SenderMobileNo">abc@abc.com</Attribute>
                <Content  Name="MobileNo">abc@abc.com</Content>
                <Content  Value="TxnNO">abc@abc.com</Content>
                <ERCo   ercvalue="ERCNO">abc@abc.com</ERCo>
                <Attribute Name="OrderHeader"><![CDATA[" and ends with "]]></Attribute>         
            </AttributeList>
        </MessageDetails>
        <MessageDetails>
            <AttributeList>
                <Attribute Name="CcEmailAddress">abc@abc.com</Attribute>
                <Attribute Name="BcccEmailAddress">abc@abc.com</Attribute>
                <Attribute Name="SenderEmailAddress">abc@abc.com</Attribute>
                <Attribute Name="SenderMobileNo">abc@abc.com</Attribute>
                <Content  Name="MobileNo">abc@abc.com</Content>
                <Content  Value="TxnNO">abc@abc.com</Content>
                <ERCo   ercvalue="ERCNO">abc@abc.com</ERCo>
                <Attribute Name="OrderHeader"><![CDATA[" and ends with "]]></Attribute>         
            </AttributeList>
        </MessageDetails>
    </SendEmail>
    </Payload>
</Root>
```

Below are my requirements and questions :

1. In the AttributeList tag , i have to lookup for attribute "Name" which has a specific value (say CcEmailAddress ) and then map the corresponding Field Value (the actual email id) to my target tag . I tried 
   //[@Name='CcEmailAddress'] 
   As it appears once in my input , i decided to traverse through all the attributes with name as Name and value as CcEmailAddress . But it doesnt seem to be working .
2. How do i ensure that my code is selecting a specific occurance ? In my case Message details repeats n-times . If i use a select inside a for-each , it fetches only the first occuring value . When loop is on the second "MessageDetails" , i would want to get the values inside them . How do i achieve this ?
3. Inside AttributeList , i hold "Attribute" element and n-others . If i wanna search through the "Content" element and find a value where attribute "Name"=MobileNo (MobileNo can appear under any tag but i want only the thing under Content which repeats), how do i do it ?

Thanks a lot for your help .

Comment: Please, edit the question and specify the exact wanted result from the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think the best choice here would be either `//Attribute[@Name = 'CcEmailAddress']` or a relative path containing `Attribute[@Name = 'CcEmailAddress']` depending on what the context node is.
2. You can use relative XPaths. If the context node is MessageDetails, then you can use the path `AttributeList/Attribute[@Name = 'CcEmailAddress']`
3. Similarly to the above, if you only want to consider `Content` element values, then you can use a path containing `Content[@Name = 'MobileNo']`. Again, since you are iterating through `MessageDetails`, this would probably be `AttributeList/Content[@Name = 'MobileNo']`